# Executing a bash script via php

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

Good day all, I m trying to implement a web interface that will operate my wireless network.

One of the operations is to configure my card into monitor mode. pretty simple, if you run this command:

```
bash prepareCard.sh wlan0
```

and the script prepareCard.sh is as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
IFACE=$1
ifconfig $IFACE down
iwconfig $IFACE mode monitor
ifconfig $IFACE up
```

Now I want to execute this script via a php script:

```
$cmd = shell_exec("bash prepareCard.sh wlan0");
```

when I check if the card has been set to monitor mode, nothing! it's still in management mode!!
Can you please tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: I am not sure.check your `php file` and `prepareCard.sh` are in same folder path.And try the shell execution with  `$cmd = shell_exec("./prepareCard.sh wlan0");`

Comment: Check if the user that is running the php script has permissions to run these commands, I'd guess those require to be run with root privileges.

Comment: @prasad I checked that too, both files are in the same directory, and I'm running KALI linux, which uses the root user as default one

Comment: Are you check the file permission of `prepareCard.sh` file `chmod +x prepareCard.sh`

Comment: Are you executing the php script in a command line or via a web server? Web servers execute the scripts as a special user (usually `www-data:www-data`) which usually does not have the highest permissions by default.

Comment: @KoCour Yes, I m running the script thru web server. I also figured this might be the issue... The problem now is how do I get past this? is there a way? Or should I initiate a new question?

Comment: @PhoenixBlue I posted a possible solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the webserver user that is running the script does not have sufficient permissions, you can try this way to fix it:

Use command `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers` and add this line:

```
ALL    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /absolute/path/prepareCard.sh
```

Make sure to set permissions `700` to the script, so no one else can edit it. Then execute your script with `sudo` like this:

```
$cmd = shell_exec("sudo /absolute/path/prepareCard.sh wlan0");
```

That should execute the script as root without a need to enter a password.

Comment: YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER!! THANKS SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

One good way to debug BASH scripts is to set debug mode on (either by passing an `-x` flag to bash in your `shell_exec` call, by running `set -x`, or in the shebang line `#!/bin/bash -x`). This shows you what's going on during execution of the bash script. In your case, I suggest the first case, since you don't know if the script is even being loaded in the first place.

```
$cmd = shell_exec("bash -x prepareCard.sh wlan0");
```

After that, you should have more in your $cmd variable.